# How to install latex packages in kile under Ubuntu

Tags: packages, kile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

I successfully installed tex live 2011 from [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) running the install-tl script. I then exported the path using export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH i opened kile but i am getting an error: *! LaTeX Error: File newfloat.sty not found*, when i run pdflatex inside a `tex` with `usepackage{float}`

After running `tlmgr install newfloat`. I got this: *tlmgr: package repository ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/texlive/tlnet TeX Live 2011 is frozen forever and will no longer be updated. This happens in preparation for a new release.*

How am i sure the kile is compliant with the new installed packages?

Comment: The `newfloat` package is part of `caption`, so you should do `tlmgr update caption`. The message says that no new update will ever be done to TeX Live 2011, but you can still update your distribution to the last snapshot.

Comment: I get the same error even when i run `tlmgr update caption`. I did it to see whether or not it has been installed. How can i fix this?What do you mean by last snapshot? It seems that texlive rep is dead

Comment: The message is not an error. If you run `tlmgr show caption`, what's the number shown near `revision:`?

Comment: i run `find /usr/local/texlive/2011 -name newfloat.sty` and it's there.But kile can't involve it. I am trying to configure kile to take care of the new package but i can't find out a way of doing it

Comment: Run `sudo mktexlsr`

Comment: i run it i run again kile and i got the same error:`not found newfloat.sty`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3511/discussion-between-egreg-and-curious)

Comment: problem fixed with the help of @egreg at chat. He a real tex prof

Comment: Closed as a 'reverse dupe': we've now got a proper answer for the general case.